# Function to accept a set of types

Tags: function, rust, types

Suppose I have the following `structs`:

```rust
struct Oranges { i: i32 }
struct Apples { i: i32 }
struct Chairs { i: i32 }
```

I can define a set of `Apples` and `Oranges` and count them up as a bunch of fruits.

```rust
let o = Oranges{i: 4};
let a = Apples{i: 3};
let fruits = o.i + a.i;
println!("I have {} fruits", fruits)  // I have 7 fruits.
```

If I write a function I can do this dynamically, but this is restrictive becuase argument 1 must be `Apples` and argument 2 must be `Oranges`.

```
fn count(a: &Apples, o: &Oranges) -> i32 {
    a.i + o.i
}
println!("I have {} fruits", count(&a, &o));  // I have 7 fruits.
```

### How do I write `count` function that accepts either `Apples` or `Oranges` as types?

---

I realise that this must seem quite trivial to one experienced in Rust. I have introduced `Chairs` as a comparator that is not allowed.

I have tried to implement `traits` with compiler errors:

```
trait Fruit {}
impl Fruit for Apples {}
impl Fruit for Oranges {}

fn count<T, S>(a: &T, o: &S) -> i32
where T: Fruit, S: Fruit
{
    a.i + o.i
}           ^ unknown field error[E0609]
```

I have also tried to use `enums` but that just seems to create such a combinatorial mess that I assume there is a much better way.

```rust
enum Fruit{
    O(Oranges),
    A(Apples)
}

fn count(a: &Fruit, b: &Fruit) -> i32
{
    match (a, b) {
        (Fruit::O(x), Fruit::O(y)) => x.i + y.i,
        (Fruit::O(x), Fruit::A(y)) => x.i + y.i,
        (Fruit::A(x), Fruit::O(y)) => x.i + y.i,
        (Fruit::A(x), Fruit::A(y)) => x.i + y.i,
    }
}
println!("I have {} fruits", count(&Fruit::A(a), &Fruit::O(o)));  // I have 7 fruits.
```

Comment: Stop thinking about _sets_ of types and start thinking about _behaviors_ of types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

## Trait with a `count` method

Traits can't declare or access fields, so you need to have a `count` method that you implement for each type of fruit that returns the correct value:

```
trait Fruit {
    fn count (&self) -> i32;
}

impl Fruit for Apples {
    fn count (&self) -> i32 { self.i }
}

impl Fruit for Oranges {
    fn count (&self) -> i32 { self.i }
}

fn count<T, S>(a: &T, o: &S) -> i32
where T: Fruit, S: Fruit
{
    a.count() + o.count()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ae324f3ebaca936ebd38805b08eba624)

## `enum` with a `count` method to avoid the combinatorial mess

```
enum Fruit{
    O(Oranges),
    A(Apples)
}

impl Fruit {
    fn count (&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Fruit::O (o) => o.i,
            Fruit::A (a) => a.i,
        }
    }
}

fn count(a: &Fruit, b: &Fruit) -> i32
{
    a.count() + b.count()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=674a29cc54c5fd61574701c789ec6b71)

## Avoiding repetition

If you have a lot of fruit types, you can avoid repeated code for either solution with macros, e.g.:

```
trait Fruit {
    fn count (&self) -> i32;
}

macro_rules! impl_fruit {
    ($($f:ident),*) => {
        $(
            impl Fruit for $f {
                fn count (&self) -> i32 { self.i }
            }
        )*
    }
}

impl_fruit!(Apples, Oranges);

fn count<T, S>(a: &T, o: &S) -> i32
where T: Fruit, S: Fruit
{
    a.count() + o.count()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5735407803e9816f8cb58a8a515ca3f1)

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Good to know I was on the right track with possibilities but there were ways to improve each. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Based off  @Jmb's answer, you can also pass a slice of boxed trait objects to a `sum()` function:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "dyn_arg"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

`src/lib.rs`

```rust
pub struct Oranges {
    i: i32,
}
pub struct Apples {
    i: i32,
}
pub struct Chairs {
    i: i32,
}

impl Apples {
    #[must_use]
    pub const fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
        Self { i }
    }
}

impl Oranges {
    #[must_use]
    pub const fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
        Self { i }
    }
}

impl Chairs {
    #[must_use]
    pub const fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
        Self { i }
    }
}

pub trait Countable {
    fn count(&self) -> i32;
}

impl Countable for Oranges {
    fn count(&self) -> i32 {
        self.i
    }
}

impl Countable for Apples {
    fn count(&self) -> i32 {
        self.i
    }
}

impl Countable for Chairs {
    fn count(&self) -> i32 {
        self.i
    }
}

#[must_use]
pub fn sum(countables: &[Box<dyn Countable>]) -> i32 {
    countables.iter().map(|countable| countable.count()).sum()
}
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use dyn_arg::{sum, Apples, Countable, Oranges};

fn main() {
    let apples = Apples::new(42);
    let oranges = Oranges::new(1337);
    let s = sum(&[
        Box::new(apples) as Box<dyn Countable>,
        Box::new(oranges) as Box<dyn Countable>,
    ]);
    println!("Sum: {s}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also very helpful to see the different ways of implementing this helps to demonstrate new concepts also that I may not be aware of.